How to display multiple elements using pagination? aiogram 3
Please tell me how to give the user not 1 element, but 5 elements at once, and on the last 5 element, the previous and next keys should be assigned. When clicking next, the bot should send the next 5 items
Now I get 1 element at a time with the ability to scroll to the next one. But since in the future there will be more products in the bot, I would like to make it send 5 items to the chat at once.
class Paginator:
def __init__(self, array: list | tuple, page: int=1, per_page: int=1):
    self.array = array
    self.per_page = per_page
    self.page = page
    self.len = len(self.array)
    # math.ceil - округление в большую сторону до целого числа
    self.pages = math.ceil(self.len / self.per_page)

def __get_slice(self):
    start = (self.page - 1) * self.per_page
    stop = start + self.per_page
    return self.array[start:stop]

def get_page(self):
    page_items = self.__get_slice()
    return page_items

def has_next(self):
    if self.page < self.pages:
        return self.page + 1
    return False

def has_previous(self):
    if self.page > 1:
        return self.page - 1
    return False


def pages(paginator: Paginator):
    btns = dict()
    if paginator.has_previous():
        btns["◀ Пред."] = "previous"

    if paginator.has_next():
        btns["След. ▶"] = "next"

    return btns


async def products(session, level, category, page):
    products = await orm_get_products(session, category_id=category)

    paginator = Paginator(products, page=page)
    product = paginator.get_page()[0]

    image = InputMediaPhoto(
        media=product.image,
        caption=f"<strong>{product.name}\
                </strong>\n{product.description}\nСтоимость: {round(product.price, 2)}\n\
                <strong>Товар {paginator.page} из {paginator.pages}</strong>",
    )

    pagination_btns = pages(paginator)

    kbds = get_products_btns(
        level=level,
        category=category,
        page=page,
        pagination_btns=pagination_btns,
        #product_id=product.id,
    )

    return image, kbds


async def get_menu_content(
        session: AsyncSession,
        level: int,
        menu_name: str,
        category: int | None = None,
        page: int | None = None,
):

    if level == 0:
        return await main_menu(session, level, menu_name)
    elif level == 1:
        return await catalog(session, level, menu_name)
    elif level == 2:
        return await products(session, level, category, page)


which piece of the large code is causing the problem ?

users dont need all the code, the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example
